# Google Guava newConcurrentMap base implementation

Tags: java, dictionary, guava, concurrenthashmap

How is the newConcurrentMap implemented in backend? I mean is it based on a hashmap (buckets) or there is some other backend implementation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently it returns a `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: See [Maps.java:304](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a2a2ebb9aa29a5d24182f394125121129f936155/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Maps.java#L304) and [MapMaker.java:520](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.java#L520).